# Is "shpritzing" an invented word?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In an episode of the big bang theory, someone says "Take a jacket, it's shpritzing a little." Is shpritzing are real word? What does it mean?

Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=big-bang-theory&episode=s02e14

Comment: "bin bang theory" - also, beware of confusing British readers, because a 'bin bag'  is a 'trash bag'. A black plastic bag for refuse.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who said it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a real word. It's generally spelled *spritz*, even though it is commonly pronounced *shprits*. What it means in this context is not *raining* but *raining lightly*, or in non-Yiddish-influenced English, *drizzling*.

The word *spritz* came from Yiddish or German; in German [*spritzen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spritzen) means *to squirt*. In Yiddish the corresponding word is [*shpritsn*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A4%D6%BC%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%9F#Yiddish) (שפּריצן).  It was originally pronounced with an *sh*: *shpritz*, because that's the way it's pronounced in German and Yiddish. It still commonly is pronounced that way.

Answer (score 4):

I know this word as *spritz* (in terms of spelling), and /sprɪts/ (in terms of pronunciation). The dictionary gives both pronunciations (with and without *sh*):

> [spritz](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spritz) verb
>   \ˈsprits, ˈshprits\
>   spritzed; spritzing; spritzes
>   Definition of spritz
>
> transitive verb
>   : spray
>
> intransitive verb
>   : to disperse or apply a spray
>
> (M-W)
>
> [spritz](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/spritz)
>   / sprɪts, ʃprɪts /
>   verb (used with object)
>   1 to spray briefly and quickly; squirt:
>   *He spritzed a little soda in his drink.*
>
> (Dictionary.com)

I see original as somewhat unusual, but understandable. Given the context, I take it to mean that it's raining. Again, this is unusual to me, but possible, as a kind of improvisation, or "creative" utterance. Maybe it has greater currency among other speakers.

Comment: The word originally comes from Yiddish or German, so the original pronunciation was *shpritz*. And it doesn't quite mean *raining*; it means  *drizzling (raining lightly*),

Comment: @PeterShor please add your comment as an answer. It's what I would have written, as a guess. I think it's worthy of an official answer.